# Html.DropDownlistFor selectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Having a hard time getting this dropDownList to Bind. This is simply a list of states. The Model.State is "TX", but my dropdownlist is showing "AK", which is the first value in the list. Any thoughts?

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(
                 model => model.State,
                 new SelectList(
                               muniSynd.getStatecodesDropDown(),
                               "Value",
                               "Text",
                               Model.State.ToString().Trim()
                 )
              )

            %>
```

In my muniSynd class, which is a wrapper of my dataContext.....

```
public IList<StateCodeViewModel> getStatecodesDropDown()
        {
            var states = from p in this._MuniDc.Statecodes
                         select new StateCodeViewModel
                         {
                             Value = p.Statecode1.ToString().Trim(),
                             Text = p.Statecode1.ToString().Trim()
                         };
            return states.ToList();
        }



public class StateCodeViewModel
    {
        public string Value{get;set;}
        public string Text{get;set;}
    }
```

Im using LinqToSQL, here is the object

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Statecodes")]
    public partial class Statecode
    {

        private string _Statecode1;

        public Statecode()
        {
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="Statecode", Storage="_Statecode1", DbType="NVarChar(3)")]
        public string Statecode1
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Statecode1;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Statecode1 != value))
                {
                    this._Statecode1 = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your problem, but my example below works fine:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

         viewModel.State = "TX";

         return this.View(viewModel);
     }

         public static IList<StateCodeViewModel> getStatecodesDropDown()
         {
             var stateCodes = new List<string> { "AX", "GH", "TX" };

             var states = from p in stateCodes
                          select new StateCodeViewModel
                          {
                              Value = p,
                              Text = p
                          };
             return states.ToList();
         }
    }

    public class IndexViewModel
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

    public class StateCodeViewModel
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using MVCWorkbench.Controllers
@model IndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State,
                      new SelectList(HomeController.getStatecodesDropDown(),
                               "Value",
                               "Text",
                               Model.State.ToString().Trim()
                 )
              )
```

Not sure what to suggest other then check that the State value is in the dropdown list. Also this could be a case-sensitivity issue perhaps?

Comment: first off, thanks for spending this much time with it.  When using linq, I have realized that a state is returned as "TX ". I thought the trim would take care of that. If you change your viewModel.State = "TX ";   <----that includes the space, does it work for you? I am directly binding my model to a LinqObject, and maybe what I need to do is bind it to a ViewModel.If I understand correctly, as long as I name the variables in the ViewModel the same as the variables in my linqObject, when I do an edit, update command, I can call updateModel() and it will map to my form collection values. Right?

Comment: Hi there.If you keep the names consistent then yes, the default MVC model binder will be able to match up the values during a `POST`. As for the Trim( not working, I'm not sure what's going on there. The code  looks fine. Can't see why `Model.State` would still have a space in there.